# Error in Postman: Error: write EPROTO 8768:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:

Tags: ssl, postman

During request GET in Postman (https://localhost:9001/test)
I've received an error:

*Error: write EPROTO 8768:error:1408F10B:SSL **routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number**:c:\users\administrator\buildkite-agent\builds\pm-electron\postman\electron-release\vendor\node\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:252:*

*Warning: This request did not get sent completely and might not have all the required system headers*.

Postman Configuration:

- SSL certificate verification is disabled;
- Proxy configuration - Default Proxy Configuration and Proxy configurations for sending requests are disabled;
- Request timeout in ms - 0.

Comment: This error message typically happens if you try HTTPS communication on something that is not HTTPS but more HTTP (that is not speaking TLS at all). Make sure your endpoint is HTTPS.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek comment should be the top answer

Comment: I solved it from here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60936241/5783617

Answer (score 80):

For Localhost we don't really need https, please try with http://localhost:9001/test

Comment: I am facing too with localhost, seems some problem with postman proxy configuration

Answer (score 28):

it has to be the http not https for localhost

"http://localhost:3000"

NOT

"https://localhost:3000"

Answer (score 22):

check that you are using the `HTTP` protocol not `HTTPS` to send requests to the server:

#### example

```js
export const config = {
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:4000"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host:'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:587,
    secure:false,
    requireTLC:true,
    auth: {
        user:'youmail@gmail.com',
        pass:'youpass'
    }
}
```

Notice that `secure:` is `false`.

The error occurs when `secure:` is `true`.

Comment: This almost never the correct awnser. You are making thing more insecure by default. For local environments this can sometime be what you need to do but never do this in production. It will make your application more insecure and vulnerable for man in the middle attacks.

Answer (score 1):

the reason was in an incorrect link.
In the controller I have used

@RequestMapping(value="/{baseSiteId}/test")

And this {baseSiteId} was not what I expected.