# Cannot convert undefined or null to object in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

Hey I am building a login page with Next.js and next-auth
I have also written in providers array in `[...nextauth].js`.

But when I run the code (given below):-

```
import { getProviders, signIn } from "next-auth/react";

function Login({ providers }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src="/spot-it-aye.png" alt="" />

      {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
        <div key={provider.name}>
          <button
            onClick={() => signIn(provider.id, { callbackUrl: "/" })}>
            Login With {provider.name}
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  let providers = await getProviders();

  return {
    props: {
      providers,
    },
  };
}
```

I get the

[image: errorImage]

This is the console at compilation

```
[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error request to https://localhost:3000/api/auth/providers failed, reason: write 
EPROTO 12752:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:332:
 {
  error: {
    message: 'request to https://localhost:3000/api/auth/providers failed, reason: write EPROTO 12752:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\\ws\\deps\\openssl\\openssl\\ssl\\record\\ssl3_record.c:332:\n',
    stack: 'FetchError: request to https://localhost:3000/api/auth/providers failed, reason: write EPROTO 12752:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\\ws\\deps\\openssl\\openssl\\ssl\\record\\ssl3_record.c:332:\n' +       
      '\n' +
      '    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (E:\\Coding\\VSCode\\Next JS\\spotify-2.0\\node_modules\\node-fetch\\lib\\index.js:1461:11)\n' +
      '    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:390:28)\n' +
      '    at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:475:12)\n' +
      '    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)\n' +
      '    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)\n' +
      '    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:475:12)\n' +
      '    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)\n' +
      '    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)\n' +
      '    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)',
    name: 'FetchError'
  },
  path: 'providers',
  message: 'request to https://localhost:3000/api/auth/providers failed, reason: write EPROTO 12752:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\\ws\\deps\\openssl\\openssl\\ssl\\record\\ssl3_record.c:332:\n'
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Note: I tried using

Comment: Can you attach what `providers` returns?

Comment: Make sure that the Object exists before trying to map the object:
`{Object && Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (`

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Error in Postman: Error: write EPROTO 8768:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3\_get\_record:wrong version number:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61916754/error-in-postman-error-write-eproto-8768error1408f10bssl-routinesssl3-get)? Change your `localhost` URL to use `HTTP` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue. I was able to get the providers object inside `getServerSideProps` but it was not passing down as it should be inside the page. So it has to do with how my `_app.tsx` was configured to receive the `pageProps`.

I was following along a tutorial and below was how my app was configured to receive page props which was the problem:

```js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps:{ session, pageProps} }: AppProps) {
    
    console.log(session);
    return (
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </SessionProvider>
    )
}

export default MyApp
```

I changed the app function to below which actually made sure my pages are receiving the `pageProps` without any problem:

```js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    return (
        <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </SessionProvider>
    )
}

export default MyApp
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your `next.js` version as `next-auth/react` implementation is different based on its version.

I doubt if there is already another application is running on your localhost with the same port number. Or you are using `https` instead of `http` for the `next.js` dev server.

Comment: This should be added as a comment and not as an answer. Answers are strictly for solving the OP's problems.