Can't use proxy with axios
I tried hundreds of times and  to use proxy with axios and its not work
Can anyone explain whats the problem please?
I'm gonna to drop a simple code explaining the problem
const axios = require('axios');

// Make the GET request with Axios and the proxy agent
axios.get('https://ip.smartproxy.com', {
    proxy: {
        host: '185.122.168.215',
        port: 34991
        // no need to user and password cuz i already in the whitelist 
        // i tryied free proxy and its not work 
    }
})
.then(response => {
    console.log('Response:', response.data);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
});

I really tried everything and I don't know what could to do
the output is :
cause: Error: write EPROTO B4370000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:355:

at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (node:internal/stream_base_commons:94:16) {
    errno: -4046,
    code: 'EPROTO',
    syscall: 'write'
  }
}

output img

maybe you must define the protocol into the proxy option like axios documentation.
https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config
I've view this error in other link where @Patrick Mevzek suggests this:

This error message typically happens if you try HTTPS communication on
something that is not HTTPS but more HTTP.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61916754/error-in-postman-error-write-eproto-8768error1408f10bssl-routinesssl3-get

